# Can System.Data.SqlTypes datatypes be used in asmx-style .NET Web Services?

Tags: vb.net, web-services

It looks like they are converted to regular date types in the generated proxy object.

I'd like to optionally pass null values for these dates.

Other than switching to WCF (no time to learn it right now), what is the best way to handle this situation. It looks like I also cannot pass NULLABLE date types.

Comment: I guess I could adopt the "prtend 1-1-1900' is the same as a NULL date. Yuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this.
But, wouldn't `Nullable<DateTime>` help?

Comment: My mistake  Nullable(Of Date) is permitted in a WebService. I had the syntax wrong. ty